# Error: does not contain a method named op_addition

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to remove everyone's Chrome cache directory with the following script but it keeps failing on this ridiculous error that makes no sense at all.

> method invocation failed because system.io.directoryinfo does not contain a method named op_addition

Even when I just write the $loc to the console window I get the error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$path = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
ForEach ($folder in $path) {
    $loc = $folder + "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache"
#   Remove-Item $loc
    Write-Host $loc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you are trying to do is concatenate 2 string, but `$folder` is not a string. It's a `system.io.directoryinfo` object, do something like this instead:

```
$loc = $folder.FullName + "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache"
```

$Folder.Fullname returns a string and that can be concatenated.